# sequence of complex polynomials $p_n$ s.t. $p_n(0) = 1$ for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $p_n(z) \to 0$ for each $\mathbb{C}-\{0\}$?

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

> Is there a sequence of complex polynomials $p_n$ s.t. $p_n(0) = 1$ for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $p_n(z) \to 0$ for each $z \in \mathbb{C} \setminus \{0\}$?

Any help with this would be great!

Comment: Consider $p_n(z):=1+ \frac {z^n} {n!}.$

Comment: @user64494 That goes to $1$ for all $z$, not $0$.

Comment: This is explicitly proved in "Pointwise Limits of Analytic Functions", Kennith Davidson, Amer. Math. Monthly, Vol 90, No. 6 (1983), as a consequence of Runge's theorem.

Comment: @ Omran Kouba : it is strange: I find nothing neither in [ZMATH](http://zbmath.org/authors/?s=0&c=100&q=Kenneth+Davidson) nor in [MRlookup](http://www.ams.org/mrlookup), searching for  "Pointwise Limits of Analytic Functions", Kenneth Davidson, Amer. Math. Monthly, Vol 90, No. 6 (1983)

Comment: @user64494, Nothing is strange, you didn't search hard, look here: http://webs.um.es/beca/Docencia/1112.ac/2975578.pdf

Answer (score 2):

Yes, such a sequence exists.
Use the polynomials $Q_n$ defined in
[this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/748741/68107)
to a very similar question.
From that answer:

> $Q_n$ is a polynomial that is less than $\frac1{n(n+1)}$ on $K_n^\times$ and such that $Q_n(0)=1$. Thus $Q_n(x)\to0$ pointwise on $\Bbb C^\times$.

I have been trying to come up with a simpler explicit construction but I have not been able to.